# FCM signature verification error in php using openssl_verify

Tags: php, token, jwt

I'm new in JWT and I'm trying to verify the FCM ID token Signature in php.
here is my public key browsed from [here](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com).

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n/blv4sd/fIid/xuABB6XbmFslP0BQxFhiJrtMy66Txc=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

header and payload data after decode is perfectly fine but if i try to  verify the signature it throws the following error

```
'OpenSSL unable to verify data: error:04091077:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:wrong signature length'
```

I'm using jwt-php one i found in github
https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

Please advise me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What *exact* code did you try to execute when you got that error?